# Conditions for an orthogonal matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be given $n \times n$ real non-singular matrices and consider the system of equations 
$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}B_1 \\ B_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}C\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I \\ Q \end{bmatrix} \hspace{2em}(1)$$
where $C$,$Q$, and each $A_{i,j}$ are unknown $n\times n$ matrices, and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Question 1: Under what conditions do the blocks $A_{i,j}$ and $C$ exist such that (1) is satisfied and $Q$ is either orthogonal or skew-symmetric? How would one go about identifying such a $Q$.

ADDED QUESTION:

Question 2: If we further impose that the $A_{i,j}$'s should be diagonal, when is it possible to identify the $A_{i,j}$'s, $C$ and $Q$ such that (1) is satisfied and $Q$ is either orthogonal or skew-symmetric?

Attempted solution to question 2: Let $D=\begin{bmatrix}I\\Q\end{bmatrix}$. Then, if $Q$ was known, we could iterate the equations
\begin{eqnarray} A^{k} &=& \arg\min_{A}\|ABC^{k-1}-D\|_{F}^2 \text{ s.t. }A \text{ is tridiagonal}\\ C^{k} &=& \arg\min_{C}\|A^{k}BC-D\|_{F}^2 \\
\end{eqnarray}
to identify an answer when one existed. Each problem is a closed-form projection since the problem is simply least squares.

However, we don't know $Q$, only a desired property of $Q$. Maybe there's a third projector to add to the mix:
\begin{eqnarray} A^{k} &=& \arg\min_{A}\|ABC^{k-1}-D^{k-1}\|_{F}^2 \text{ s.t. }A \text{ is tridiagonal}\\ C^{k} &=& \arg\min_{C}\|A^{k}BC-D^{k-1}\|_{F}^2 \\ D^{k} &=& \arg\min_{D}\|A^{k}BC^{k}-D\|_{F}^2\\ \end{eqnarray}
where the projector to update $D^k$ is what I can't figure out. For orthogonal $Q$ I've tried using the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) to come up with one, but haven't been able to yet.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: $C$ is not given. $Q$ is not given, but the $Q$ which results from selecting the $A_{ij}$s and $C$ should be orthogonal.

Comment: Exactly, with the intent to get a right hand side that works out to be identity stacked on top of an orthogonal (or skew symmetric) $Q$. The purpose of $C$ is so that the range of $AB$ is the range of $\pmatrix{I\\ Q}$

Answer (score 1):

In each question, the equation is always solvable.

Let $\mathbf B=\pmatrix{B_1\\ B_2}$. Pick *any* $Q$ you desire (orthogonal, skew-symmetric, whatever). Perform a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) $\mathbf B=U\Sigma V^T$. Since $\mathbf B$ has full column rank, its singular value matrix $\Sigma$ must be of the form $\pmatrix{D\\ 0}$, where $D$ is an invertible diagonal matrix. Now, put $C=V$ and
$$
\mathbf A=\pmatrix{D^{-1}&0\\ QD^{-1}&0}U^T,
$$
we get $\mathbf A\mathbf BC=\pmatrix{I\\ Q}$. Divide $\mathbf A$ into four sub-blocks of equal sizes, we get $A_{11}=D^{-1},\ A_{21}=QD^{-1}$ and $A_{12}=A_{22}=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious, since it seems $A_{12}$ and $A_{22}$ were in some sense unnecessary, what if we imposed restrictions on the $A_{i,j}$'s such as they each had to be diagonal.

Comment: @curiousStudent In case both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are invertible (rather than merely $\mathbf B$ has full column rank), you may simply put $C=I,\ A_{11}=B_1^{-1},\ A_{22}=QB_2^{-1}$ and $A_{12}=A_{21}=0$.

Comment: Lets pick $B_1=I$ and assume restrict the $A_{ij}'s$ to be diagonal, then it would have to be that Q diagonalizes $B_2^{-1}$. However, lets say  $B_2^{-1}$ isn't diagonalized by a skew-symmetric or orthogonal matrix. Can $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ compensate in some cases?

Comment: @curiousStudent Sorry, I mistakenly thought you meant $\mathbf A$ is block-diagonal. You mean the blocks themselves are diagonal? This is not always do-able (actually, it's usually not achievable).

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{A}_{12}\\
\mathbf{A}_{21} & \mathbf{A}_{22}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{B}_1\\
\mathbf{B}_2
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf{C}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{I}\\
\mathbf{Q}
\end{array}
\right]. \tag 1
$$

We obtain
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbf{A}_{11} \mathbf{B}_1 \mathbf{C}
    + \mathbf{A}_{12} \mathbf{B}_2 \mathbf{C}
&=& \mathbf{I}\\
\mathbf{A}_{21} \mathbf{B}_1 \mathbf{C}
    + \mathbf{A}_{22} \mathbf{B}_2 \mathbf{C}
&=& \mathbf{Q}
\end{array}
\right. \tag 2
$$

Given any $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}$ and $\mathbf{C}$.

Assuming that the required inverses are defined,
expression (2) can be written as
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11} \mathbf{B}_1
    +  \mathbf{B}_2
&=& \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{C}^{-1}\\
\mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \mathbf{B}_1
    + \mathbf{B}_2
&=& \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{C}^{-1}
\end{array}
\right. \tag 3
$$

Whence

> $$
> \mathbf{B}_1
> =
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \big)^{-1}
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \tag 4
> $$

Assuming that the required inverses are defined,
expression (2) can be written as
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbf{B}_1
    + \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12} \mathbf{B}_2
&=& \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{C}^{-1}\\
\mathbf{B}_1
    + \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \mathbf{B}_2
&=& \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{C}^{-1}
\end{array}
\right. \tag 5
$$

Whence

> $$
> \mathbf{B}_2
> =
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \big)^{-1}
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \tag 6
> $$

---

Conclusion:

> So whatever property $\mathbf{Q}$ has,
>   given any $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}$ and $\mathbf{C}$,
>       such that:
>
> $\bullet$ $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}^{-1}$
>
> $\bullet$ $\big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}
>             - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \big)^{-1}$
>
> $\bullet$ $\big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}
>             - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \big)$
>
> $\bullet$ $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$
>
> are all defined, then we can find the corresponding $\mathbf{B}_k$
>   $$
> \mathbf{B}_1
> =
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \big)^{-1}
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1}\\
> \mathbf{B}_2
> =
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \big)^{-1}
> \big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1}
>     - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1}
> $$
>    such that
>   $$
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{A}_{12}\\
> \mathbf{A}_{21} & \mathbf{A}_{22}
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> \mathbf{B}_1\\
> \mathbf{B}_2
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \mathbf{C}
> =
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> \mathbf{I}\\
> \mathbf{Q}
> \end{array}
> \right].
> $$

---

We have used
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{A}_{12}\\
\mathbf{A}_{21} & \mathbf{A}_{22}
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}
    - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \big)^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1}
& - \big( \mathbf{A}_{12}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}
    - \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21} \big)^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22}^{-1}\\
\big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}
    - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \big)^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1}
& - \big( \mathbf{A}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{12}
    - \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{22} \big)^{-1} \mathbf{A}_{21}^{-1}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
(The online editor halted, could no longer see preview)

From (2) also follows that when $\mathbf{B}_k$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are given,
we get

> $$
> \mathbf{A}_{11} = \big( \mathbf{I}/2 + \mathbf{X} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_1^{-1}$$
>   $$\mathbf{A}_{12} = \big( \mathbf{I}/2 - \mathbf{X} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_2^{-1}$$
>   $$\mathbf{A}_{21} = \big( \mathbf{Q}/2 + \mathbf{Y} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_1^{-1}$$
>   $$\mathbf{A}_{22} = \big( \mathbf{Q}/2 - \mathbf{Y} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_2^{-1}
> $$

where $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are arbitrary.

Comment: Very interesting, although the intent of my original question was to be given  the $B_k$ and a desired property for $Q$, generate the $A_{i,j}$'s, $C$, and $Q$.

Comment: @curiousStudent AHHHHHH --- I worked it out the other way around, sorry. I will think about the problem of finding the $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}$...

Comment: I've updated the question to try and make it clearer. I've also added a second part which I'm more interested in.

Comment: Your question can be solved from (2).

You get

$\mathbf{A}_{11} = \big( \mathbf{I}/2 + \mathbf{X} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_1^{-1}$,

$\mathbf{A}_{12} = \big( \mathbf{I}/2 - \mathbf{X} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_2^{-1}$

$\mathbf{A}_{21} = \big( \mathbf{Q}/2 + \mathbf{Y} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_1^{-1}$

$\mathbf{A}_{22} = \big( \mathbf{Q}/2 - \mathbf{Y} \big) \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{B}_2^{-1}$

Comment: But doesn't $X$ and $Y$ depend on the $A_{i,j}$'s? Also, doesn't this imply $C$ is known>

Comment: No, they are arbitrary

Comment: But $Q$ and $C$ are also unknown. I see now that that solves the general case if $Q$ and $C$ are fixed. But If we dont fix $Q$ I dont see how it implies a property of $Q$.

Comment: Both $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are arbitrary. When we have an equation involving $n$ parameters, then we can express on parameters in terms of the other $n-1$ parameters.

Properties propagate through such expression. Say $\mathbf{X} = 0$, $\mathbf{Y} = 0$.

When $\mathbf{Q}$ is orthogonal and $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{B}_k$ is not, then $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}$ is no orthogonal.

When $\mathbf{Q}$,$\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{B}_k$ are orthogonal , then $\mathbf{A}_{k\ell}$ is also orthogonal.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks! In thinking about question 2 ($A_{i,j}$'s being diagonal) It doesn't seem to me that we can solve such a system in closed form.